# How can I make the image fill the whole container with a set height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my image to take up the whole container with a set height of 350px without sacrificing its aspect ratio

I tried this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="background-container" >
   <img src="bgImageUrl" class="img-responsive" height="350px">

.background-container {
  max-height: 350px;
}
```

The image is 1400x700. When I set the height to 350px it just covers the left side and the rest as a blank space. And setting its width to 100% just stretched the image

**EDIT**

I also want the image responsive (hence the `img-responsive` class) so when the screen is smaller it'll shrink as well

Comment: `.background-container, .background-container .img-responsive { max-height: 350px; }` ... the responsive image class forces `height:auto` to your image; overriding your height declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this? Move the image to a class so looks like this. Also is responsive and scales as the page gets smaller.

```css
.background-container {
  height: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/68672/beach-beverage-caribbean-cocktail-68672.jpeg') 0 center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

  .background-container {
    height: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/68672/beach-beverage-caribbean-cocktail-68672.jpeg') 0 center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="background-container">
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried this actually and it worked! But I'm also trying to make the height of it responsive. So the max will be 350px and when the screen size is smaller it'll lower

Comment: Is there a certain height you want it to be on smaller screen? or you just want the height to get smaller? Because then I feel like its dependent on your image

Comment: minimum height is 180px

Comment: Updated it with a media query, does that suffice? Or are you looking for that smooth transition like the image does?